# Does conjugate Bailey pair have conjugate Bailey lemma like Bailey pair have Bailey lemma?

Tags: co.combinatorics

Motivation of my question: Does conjugate Bailey pair have conjugate Bailey lemma like Bailey pair have Bailey lemma?